# Laravel if one field is filled then others are not required

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

I have three nullable fields  ( **Coupon**, **Membership**, **Offer**) which are to be filled from requests. I want to validate/restrict users so that they can only fill one of these fields.
As the fields are not required, I cannot use the required:* validators to handle this.
I know this can be handled in the front-end, but I want to do it in the backend as well.

Appreciate any help/insight on this.

Comment: Is there only ONE field that can be filled from your request that is the same every time? For example you only ever want `coupon` to be filled? Or could it be a different field each time? If different, which ones take priority over the others?

Comment: It can either be one of the three or none of them. Depends on what the user inputs, so there is no priority set here.

Comment: Okay. So if they give all three, which one do you want to set?

Comment: This sounds like the form control should be a select field or radio button where the value of the field is one of the three options that the user selects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`required_without_all` function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-without-all) from laravel validations.

```
$request->validate([
    'coupon'     => ['nullable', 'required_without_all:membership,offer'],
    'membership' => ['nullable', 'required_without_all:coupon,offer'],
    'offer'      => ['nullable', 'required_without_all:membership,coupon'],
]);
```

Comment: On giving offer as data, I receive the following error message.  `{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "coupon_id": [
            "The coupon id field is required when membership enroll id / offer id is not present."
        ],
        "membership_enroll_id": [
            "The membership enroll id field is required when coupon id / offer id is not present."
        ]
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I would take the approach of having the options as three possible values for the same field. You could use a select or radio button group on your form to fill in a single field. This way the user can only enter one of the three possible values.

If we call the field `type` for example, your validation would check that the value given for `type` is one of the three options.

```
$request->validate([
    'type' => [
          'nullable',
          Rule::in(['coupon', 'membership', 'offer']),
    ],
]);
```

EDIT:
Add the nullable validation to allow the field to have no value at all